# How to automate a ruby program?

Tags: ruby, daemon, launchd

I writed a little ruby program that collects starred emails from a mailbox and creates corresponding cards in a kanban-style list-making application (thanks to websites' API). It works fine, but for now I have to run it manually (`ruby app.rb`).
I'd like to find a way to run it continually. How can I manage to do so ?

I thought of using launchd to run a service (daemon or agent), but I don't know if it really fits my needs.

Here is my program architecture:

[image]

Comment: crontab if it's something that should run at intervals, if it's a subscriber model, then you would need to daemonize it

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have voted to close your question as being opinion-based. Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Specifically, please note _To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ...?”_

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'm gonna try to rephrase my question for it to follow the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) use cron to start program periodically, but maybe any delay between incoming mail and creating card(or something else)
2) use service or agent to minimize time delay